# Map a list sent from Javascript to Java backend

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am trying to send a list of json object from Javascript to a Spring Boot backend. This is how my function looks in the frontend:

```
function submit() {
        var toSend = JSON.stringify(toBeAdded);
        console.log(toSend);
        $.post("assets",
            toSend,
            data => {
                populate(data);
                toBeAdded = [];
            });
    }
```

So I send a list like: [{"name":"foo1","description":"bar1","value":"4"}, {"name":"foo2","description":"bar2","value":"10"}]

But I just can't catch it in the backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void insertAssets(List<AssetDto> data, HttpSession session) {
        System.out.println(data);
}
```

And AssetDto looks like:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AssetDto implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int value;
}
```

So in this case I have an error( No primary or single public constructor found for interface java.util.List - and no default constructor found either). But I tried with a String also(I get null) and with JSONArray I get an empty list. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Add  `Content-Type: application/json` header to request to mention that you send JSON data. You should use `$.ajax` function since `$.post` does not allow to add headers.

```
function submit() {
        var toSend = JSON.stringify(toBeAdded);
        console.log(toSend);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets',
            type: 'post',
            data: toSent,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data){
                        populate(data);
                        toBeAdded = [];
                     }
        });
    }
```

On the server-side use `@RequestBody` annotation before the parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void insertAssets(@RequestBody List<AssetDto> data, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: In this way I get: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported] and 415 in the console

Comment: @hackermanwow add `application\json` header to request on the client side. I will update my answer with this.